# Sqoop incremental import "Cannot append files to target dir"

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, impala

I have a problem while importing data from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop...

This query :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx/database \
    --username sqoop --password sqoop --table datatable \
    --target-dir /home/cloudera/user/hive/warehouse/database.db/datatable \
    --as-parquetfile -m 1 --append
```

Return this error :

> 15/01/14 16:27:28 WARN util.AppendUtils: Cannot append files to target dir; no such directory: _sqoop/14162350000000781_32315_servername.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu_datatable

Files are located in **/user/root/_sqoop/** this way : **/user/root/_sqoop/14162350000000781_32315_servername/ip-xx-xx-xx/eu_datatable/**

Is it normal that dots from the hostname are replaced by slashes ? It seems to be the problem but noone is complaining about this problem...

Edit : It works correctly when using text format instead of Parquet.

Thank you !

Comment: what is the version of sqoop?

Comment: I have a similar issue. 

I am running command: sqoop import --connect "..." --password "..." --username "..." --hbase-create-table --table "TRANSFER_HBASE01" --hbase-table "HBASE01" --column-family "transfer01" --target-dir "/user/mapr/TRANSFER_HBASE01" --check-column "ID" --incremental "append" --last-value 5

I am getting a warning: WARN util.AppendUtils: Cannot append files to target dir; no such directory: _sqoop/891283d89d584bf3b06c73122805e270_TRANSFER_HBASE01

I am unable to get the incremental data while reading from pig script.

Did anyone find any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same issue when running an incremental export from postgresql to avro.  It works fine without the incremental update.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I concern, it is still a problem now.

Even if you use sqoop 1.4.6, the result is still same.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2165